# TEKTRO Road Bike Mechanical Disc Brakes MD-C550 Pads

Tags: brakes, disc-brake, mechanical, tektro

About TEKTRO Road Bike Mechanical Disc Brakes MD-C550 pads
I search the internet for replacement and all results shows the model: E10.11
and in the compatibility chart it does not for the MD-C550
Please recommend something fit in

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same issue with the Trek Domane AL 2 Disk but successfully used the E10.11 with the MD-C550 disc brakes as replacement pads.

Comment: I have the same bike , so the E10.11 working with no problems? and what about noise or stopping power

Comment: @Emadness in terms of compatibility no problems. I use the bike mainly for bikepacking so the dirt and extra weight so seem to push the breaks to the limits in terms of noise and stopping power but I doubt the pads can be too blame.